inject() must be called from an injection context in unit test
When I am trying to use the AlertsComponent in my test file at the beginning it require some services. After adding theses services the following error appear:

inject() must be called from an injection context

When I am using a class that doesn't use inheritance with parent class no provider is required and the test work fine but when the test use a component that require a base class with services in constructor I have this error.
AlertBase
export abstract class AlertBase {
    constructor(protected alertService: IAlertService, protected alertResultService: IAlertResultService, protected paginationService: IPaginationService, protected selectedItemService: SelectedItemService) {
    }
}

AlertsComponent
@Component({
  selector: 'alerts',
  templateUrl: './alerts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alerts.component.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class AlertsComponent extends AlertBase implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 

  constructor(
    private storageService: StorageProvider,
    protected alertServiceProvider: AlertServiceProvider,
    protected alertResultProvider: AlertResultProvider,
    private toastNotificationService: ToastNotificationService,
    protected selectedItemService: SelectedItemService,
    protected paginationService: PaginationServiceProvider, private modalService: ModalService) {
    super(alertServiceProvider, alertResultProvider, paginationService, selectedItemService);

  }
}

Test File :
describe('AlertsComponent', () => {
  let component: AlertsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AlertsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule, 
        //MockModule(NotificationModule)
      ],
      declarations: [AlertsComponent],
      providers: [
        MockProvider(StorageProvider),
        MockProvider(AlertServiceProvider),
        MockProvider(AlertResultProvider),
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AlertsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});


Switch your AlertsComponent to standalone: true and try the following:
it('should create', async () => {
       await TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => {
            const component = new AlertsComponent();
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        });
    });


